# How to pass arguments to a custom class in python?

Tags: python, class, wxpython, arguments

How do I make the pass the Grid size (`self.CreateGrid(20,20)`) (number of rows and columns) to the custom class below?

```
import wx

class GraphicsPage(wx.grid.Grid):

    def __init__(self, parent): 
        wx.grid.Grid.__init__(self, parent, -1) 
        self.CreateGrid(20,20) 

        self.SetRowLabelSize (0) 
        self.SetMargins(0,0) 
        self.AutoSizeColumns(False) 
        self.ForceRefresh()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
import wx

class GraphicsPage(wx.grid.Grid):

    def __init__(self, parent, width, height): 
        super(GraphicsPage, self).__init__(parent, -1) 
        self.CreateGrid(width, height) 

        self.SetRowLabelSize (0) 
        self.SetMargins(0,0) 
        self.AutoSizeColumns(False) 
        self.ForceRefresh()
```

And then instantiate it with:

```
GraphicsPage (someParent, 20, 30)
```

Comment: I might be wrong here but are you sure you instantiate by passing `self` as an argument?

Comment: @ShashankGupta: This way works. `wx.grid.Grid.__init__` is an unbound method, meaning you need to pass `self` explicitly. It's generally a lot better to write `super(GraphicsPage, self).__init__(parent, -1)` instead, but in some cases (old-style classes, frameworks with unique idioms, etc.) you have to do it this way.

Comment: @ShashankGupta: However, for `wx`, there's no reason not to use `super`, and the tutorial does so, so… I'll edit the answer, and Hyperboreus can revert it if he has a reason to do so.

Comment: @ShashankGupta: Or were you asking about the last line? In that case, it makes sense. Assuming the thing that instantiates the `GraphicsPage` is the parent widget of that page (which isn't guaranteed, but is plausible, and maybe even likely), its `self` will be the intended `parent` for the `GraphicsPage'.

Comment: @abarnert I understood why `self` was passed to `super` but not why `self` has to be passed when you do `GraphicsPage(self, someParent, 20, 30)`. However, after reading your last comment, I now understand. I'm unfamiliar with `wx` and did not know that `GraphicsPage` would have a parent where `self` would be defined. Thank you.

Comment: @ShashankGupta: He wasn't originally using `super`, he was doing `wx.grid.Grid.__init__(self, parent, -1)`, and I thought at first that's what you were asking about. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @ShashankGupta: Anyway, passing `self` as the argument to a `parent` or `back` or similar parameter is a pretty common pattern whenever you have hierarchical data—GUI apps, XML processing, etc. It lets you build up a tree that can be traversed upward.

Comment: Sorry about the `self` in the call to init. Stupid, late-night error.